# D3js undefined variable creating fill color

Tags: d3.js

I create a map of provinces in Canada and fill it with a color which uses a calculated variable. If I attempt to use this calculated variable to fill the map, it is undefined although the console log shows that it is in the data. I've tried this in d3js v3 and v6.

> ```
> var polygons = map.selectAll('path')
> .data(provinces)
> .enter()
> .append('path')
> .attr('d', path)
> .attr("fill", function(d){
> console.log("d ",d)
> console.log("d.properties.emissionsRate ", (d.properties.emissionsRate)) // undefined
> console.log("d.properties.values ", (d.properties.values)) // OK
> return color(d.properties.values); // OK
> })
> .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5) // 0.5
> .attr("stroke", "#222")
> ```

console.log(d)

> ```
> d
> {type: "Feature", geometry: {…}, properties: {…}}
> geometry: {type: "MultiPolygon", coordinates: Array(96)}
> properties:
> PREABBR: "B.C."
> PRENAME: "British Columbia"
> PRFABBR: "C.-B."
> PRFNAME: "Colombie-Britannique"
> PRNAME: "British Columbia / Colombie-Britannique"
> PRUID: "59"
> emissionsRate: 169.38665016629284
> values: "65.7"
> ```

console.log of variables

> ```
> d.properties.emissionsRate undefined
> d.properties.values 65.7
> ```

Any suggestions about what is wrong? I've taken a similar approach in another map and it worked.

Comment: What happens when you print `console.log("d ",{...d})` ?

Comment: ...d  {type: "Feature", geometry: {…}, properties: {…}}geometry: {type: "MultiPolygon", coordinates: Array(96)}properties: PREABBR: "B.C."PRENAME: "British Columbia"PRFABBR: "C.-B."PRFNAME: "Colombie-Britannique"PRNAME: "British Columbia / Colombie-Britannique"PRUID: "59"emissionsRate: 169.38665016629284values: "65.7"__proto__: Objecttype: "Feature"__proto__: Object

Comment: Let's try something different: `const pData = provinces.map(p => ({...p, eRate: p.properties.emissionsRate}));` and `const polygons = map.selectAll('path').data(pData)...`. Do you see the `eRate` value or it's still undefined?

Comment: It is still undefined; I see this in the console "{type: "Feature", geometry: {…}, properties: {…}, eRate: undefined}
eRate: undefined" - there is a popup over this which says "This value was evaluated upon first expanding. It may have changed since then". I'm not sure I used the correct syntax to define pData. Did you want me to use the exact syntax you wrote? I did a console.log of pData immediately after I defined it and eRate was in the log but undefined there too.

Comment: I don't understand... You have a valid emissionsRate before call provinces.map() and see it undefined immediately after in pData?

Comment: Agreed ... that is what was confusing and caused me to post this. So the problem must be how I generated emissionsRate.

Comment: I realized that in the map that worked I calculate the new field from 2 csv files before reading the json map file whereas in this one I read the json file first. I'm going to change that and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231588/discussion-between-patriciaw-and-michael-rovinsky).

Comment: Changing the order of json fixed the problem. I fixed some other issues at the same time so I am not sure the order was the only problem but I think it was the main one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order of json fixed the problem. I fixed some other issues at the same time so I am not sure the order was the only problem but I think it was the main one.